# Parabolic reference lines on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am moving my plots into ggplot. Almost there except for this one (code got from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155588/add-95-confidence-limits-to-cumulative-plot)):

[image: ggplot plot should look like this]

```
#Set the bet sequence and the % lines
betseq <- 0:700 #0 to 700 bets
perlin <- 0.05 #Show the +/- 5% lines on the graph

#Define a function that plots the upper and lower % limit lines
dralim <- function(stax, endx, perlin) {
  lines(stax:endx, qnorm(1-perlin)*sqrt((stax:endx)-stax))
  lines(stax:endx, qnorm(perlin)*sqrt((stax:endx)-stax))
}

#Build the plot area and draw the vertical dashed lines
plot(betseq, rep(0, length(betseq)), type="l", ylim=c(-50, 50), main="", xlab="Trial Number", ylab="Cumulative Hits")
abline(h=0)
abline(v=35, lty="dashed") #Seg 1
abline(v=185, lty="dashed") #Seg 2
abline(v=385, lty="dashed") #Seg 3
abline(v=485, lty="dashed") #Seg 4
abline(v=585, lty="dashed") #Seg 5

#Draw the % limit lines that correspond to the vertical dashed lines by calling the
#new function dralim.
dralim(0, 35, perlin) #Seg 1
dralim(36, 185, perlin) #Seg 2
dralim(186, 385, perlin) #Seg 3
dralim(386, 485, perlin) #Seg 4
dralim(486, 585, perlin) #Seg 5
dralim(586, 701, perlin) #Seg 6
```

I can show how far I've got (not far):

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=num,y=s, colour=ss)) +geom_line() +stat_smooth(method="lm", formula="y~poly(x,2)")
```

[image: my attempt]

To be clear. I am plotting my data over the reference lines (top image). The bottom image shows my data and my poor attempt at getting the reference lines (which obviously hasn't worked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you were doing was fitting a parabola to your data, not drawing a previously defined parabola. It's not too hard to adapt what you had to `ggplot`.

Same start as you had (though `betseq` is not actually used anywhere)

```
#Set the bet sequence and the % lines
betseq <- 0:700 #0 to 700 bets
perlin <- 0.05 #Show the +/- 5% lines on the graph
```

Not instead of a function which draws lines, make a function which returns `geom_line`s (in a list) that are what you want. There is an implied `aes(x=x,  y=y)` which will be given in the `ggplot` declaration later, but this defines the data points that make the parabolas.

```
#Define a function that plots the upper and lower % limit lines
dralim <- function(stax, endx, perlin) {
  c(geom_line(data = data.frame(x=stax:endx, 
                                y=qnorm(1-perlin)*sqrt((stax:endx)-stax))),
    geom_line(data = data.frame(x=stax:endx, 
                                y=qnorm(perlin)*sqrt((stax:endx)-stax))))
}
```

To save repetition, define the position of the vertical lines (`edges`), which also can be used to define the left and right endpoints of the parabolas (`ranges`).

```
edges <- data.frame(x=c(0, 35, 185, 285, 485, 585, 700))
ranges <- data.frame(left = edges$x[-nrow(edges)],
                     right = edges$x[-1] + 1)
```

Now build the `ggplot`. There a single `geom_vline` to draw all the vertical lines (since we defined the positions in a single dataset). The unusual step is looping over the row (indices) of `ranges` and calling `dralim` with the corresponding left and right values (and `perlin`). This returns a list of lists of `geom_lines`, but that can just be added to a plot in the normal way and all the lines get added.  The final two scale calls are just to set the labels and, in the case of the y axis, range.

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x,  y=y)) +
  geom_vline(data=edges, aes(xintercept = x), linetype="dashed") +
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(ranges)), 
         function(r) {dralim(ranges$left[r], ranges$right[r], perlin)}) +
  scale_y_continuous("Cumulative Hits", lim=c(-50,50)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Trial Number")
```

[image]

Comment: I understood my way of doing it was wrong. Had to start somewhere. Yours looks pretty good. Thanks. Will give it a go!

Comment: Okay that looks great. But how do I go about plotting my data on top?

Comment: Don't know the format of your data, but guessing from what you showed, add `geom_line(data=a, aes(x=num, y=s, colour=ss))`.